# How do I change the tracking permission request alert language?

Tags: ios, swift, tracking, ios14

On iOS 14, we need to implement AppTrackingTransparency to request the user's permission.

This permission alert always appears in English. I would like to switch to another language, for example Portuguese.
The message I enter in Info.plist appears in Portuguese, but the title and buttons appear in English

Comment: Is the app localized for Portuguese?

Comment: Yes. It is all translated into Portuguese.
And the device language is also in Portuguese. But the permission alert remains in English

Comment: I asked, is the app localized, not whether it is translated. You say _Info.plist_, not _InfoPlist.strings_, which makes me think the app is not localized.

Comment: I don't know if I understood exactly what you meant, I'm new to programming
But I was looking at location and I set this up:
Debug > Simulate Location > Rio de Janeiro, Brazil...                                            Even putting this setting still appears in English

Comment: That's irrelevant. I'm talking about localization. If your app is not _localized_ for Portuguese, system dialogs will appear in English. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/localizing_your_app

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are merely using Portuguese *words* in your app. You have not written and structured an app that is *localized* for Portuguese. Your app's localization base language is still English.

The system texts, such as the title and buttons of the alert you're talking about, will therefore appear in English even on a device whose language is set as Portuguese.